# Why does compiling SwiftUI modifier without leading point compile?

Tags: swift, swiftui

By accident i added a modifier to my swift UI view without a leading point. And it compiled. And i can not wrap my head around why i did that.
Here some example Code:

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: DetailView(),
                    label: {
                        Text("Goto Detail")
                    })
                    navigationTitle("ContentView")
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    struct DetailView: View {
        var body: some View {
            Text("Detail View")
                .padding()
                navigationTitle("Detail")
        }
    }
```

Somehow even stranger is that the first "wrong" modifier `navigationTitle("ContentView")` does just nothing.
The second one `navigationTitle("Detail")` lets the App crash when navigating to the View during runtime.

Similar to this is

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        padding()
    }
}
```

This View does compile but just crashes, if tried to shown with Previews. And it just can't be navigated to.

I would really expect this code to not even compile.
Is somebody able to explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refer to a method by its simple name (e.g. `navigationTitle`), it's kind of like saying `self.navigationTitle`:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View")
            .padding()
        self.navigationTitle("Detail")
    }
}
```

This is valid, because `self` is also a `View`, and that modifier is available on all `View`s. It gives you a new view that is `self`, but with a navigation title of `Detail`. And you are using both of them as the `body`. Normally you can't return multiple things from a property, but it works here because the `body` protocol requirement is marked `@ViewBuilder`.

Of course, you are using `self` as the self's body, and you can't have self referencing views, so it fails at runtime.

If you add `self.` to the other cases, it's pretty easy to understand why they compile:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        self.padding() // self conforms to View, so you can apply padding()
        // padding() returns another View, so it's valid to return here
    }
}
```

"The body of `DetailView` is itself, but with some padding."

```
NavigationView {
    NavigationLink(
        destination: DetailView(),
        label: {
            Text("Goto Detail")
        })
    self.navigationTitle("ContentView")
}
```

"The navigation view consists of a navigation link, and `ContentView` itself (what `self` means here) with a navigation title of `ContentView`"

This doesn't crash immediately either because `NavigationView`'s initialiser is smart enough to ignore the junk `ContentView` that you have given it, or because there is an extra level of indirect-ness to the self-referencing. I don't think we can know exactly why it crashes/doesn't crash immediately, until SwiftUI becomes open source.